# 403 Forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied

Tags: http-status-code-403

I'm working with a project in Laravel and Reactjs. Everything works in localhost. But, after uploading in the server, all routes for Frontend Part is working. But can't access backend part. It shows the error - **403 Forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied!**

**Frontend deployed in the root folder. Here is my Frontend .htaccess code:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php82___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

######################################################################
**Backend Deployed in admin directory. Here is my backend .htaccess code:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

######################################################################
**In the admin directory there is a folder name public. In the public directory's .htaccess file code:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Have someone face this problem before? In localhost everything is working fine, but not in Server.

Comment: Please paste the vhost configuration.

Comment: Check the file permissions in your backend.